# JPA Web application : entities not refreshed instantly

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jpa, web-applications

My problem is the following :

I have a jsp form which permits to add bank operations to a bank contract. I succeeded in create operation and persist it in my db mysql. So all is good, except that when I submit the operation, i'm redirected to the contract page which lists all the operations. And unfortunately, the one I added is not displayed even though it's in my db. When I clean my Project via eclipse and I run locally, it works and the operation is displayed. So where am I wrong ?

To persist my Operation :

```
public void createOperation(Operation o) {
    em.persist(o);
    em.flush();

}
```

My entity contract :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="contrat")
private List<Operation> operations;
```

When I'm loading the contract jsp via servlet, firstly I find the contract :

```
em.find(Contrat.class, id);
```

and after I get the list of operations that I display in the jsp.

So, how could I do to have my List operations refresh instantly ?

Edit :

I just use em.refresh on my Contract entity and it works !!! It was just difficult to understand where to put it. Thank you for the answers ;)

Comment: The DB changes are visible (with typical settings) only in transactions that begin at a time that is after the original transaction has been committed. You might want to take a look at your use case to ensure that the transaction lifetimes are appropriate.

Comment: In my sql db, the insert is done instantly. If I understand well, I have to create a transaction and commit it to have entities refreshed too ?

Comment: You should read about transactions and come back and ask specific questions (as new questions!) if you have any. If that solves this current question, then updated accordingly. If not, then perhaps you can provide more details.

Comment: I just use em.refresh on my Contract entity and it works !!! It was just difficult to understand where to put it. Thank you for the answers ;)